# Why 'accessing' in 'Accessing to the room is not permitted for guest' is inappropriate?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Accessing to the room is not permitted for guest

A reference book says that 'Accessing' should be replaced by 'Access'. But I think it's correct that gerund phrase as subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the fact it is a gerund as the subject - that is fine.

The problem is that "Accessing to the room" as a standalone phrase is grammatically incorrect. It should not have the preposition.

You could say either:

- Accessing the room
- Access to the room

"Access", in this context, means to be *able* to enter a place, or to have permission to enter it, so the preposition is appropriate; but "accessing" is the action of gaining entry, not a means of reaching it, so there is no need for the preposition.

As an example, consider "swimming the channel", as opposed to "swimming *to* the channel". The latter would mean swimming as a means to reach it, whereas the former means swimming in, or across it.

Comment: I seem to get it.  when "access" is a noun, "access to" is appropriate. When "access" is a verb,  "access to" is inappropriate.   Is it right?

Comment: @rannrann exactly right

Answer (score 0):

There's a use of "To" there. When you use to, its "Access to" something. In the absence of "to", you can say "Accessing".

Let's take another example.

(1) A password is needed for _________ to account information.

(2) A password is needed for __________ account information.

What does the use of the word "to" in (1) tell you?

Comment: Someone try to get the account information that does not belong to him?  I guess I think too much

Comment: That does not seem to add much to the other answer and just raises another question.